# whats the console command to switch between open windows in linux?

Tags: kubuntu

I just updated my Ubuntu used https://github.com/davatorium/rofi for switching windows before.
don't work anymore.

i search a fast workaround.

if i move my mouse to the edge a pretty window preview of all opened apps will open.

How could i get this by a console command?

Before i have used:

```
~/sh/rofi.sh &
```

but i cant use this anymore because i get no GUI only this warning:
`Rofi-WARNING **: 21:12:09.679: Failed to set locale.`

Comment: The "error" you posted is not an error. Rofi should be working fine. What DE/WM are you using?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean by "DE/WM". At the moment Rofi does nothing any more.

Comment: this is my workaround at the moment: https://gist.github.com/b96783d4300ffd5a6f493ba2b58eb78b AutoKey takes the shortcut for the moment Alt+Tab

Comment: What desktop environment or window manager are you using?

Comment: ### System
```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.xx
KDE Plasma Version: 5.xxx
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.xx
Qt Version: 5.xx
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: Normally "The Alt+Tab keyboard shortcut allows to quickly switch between opened applications in Ubuntu desktop." ( [ubuntuhandbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/alt-tab-display-separate-windows-ubuntu-18-04/)  ) Do you know my the app behind? so i could call it from bash-script?

Comment: KDE Plasma is the app behind. I'm not sure if there is a way to fake the keypress, but it could work

Comment: @RayWu there is a way behind. they told my for some month. i forgot the name and cant find by search engines.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118084/discussion-between-ray-wu-and-sl5net).

Comment: Rofi still works. The issue is with your script. A command such as `rofi -modi window -show window` will allow you to switch windows using rofi.

Comment: @vanadium Then we have to differentiate more. It works in your system and not mine for some reason. My self-written Phython script has not changed for months. My Kubunto maybe too much. Also with your bash line I get the same warning as stated in the question but no other reults

Comment: I dont know way rofi is here not visible. Tried fix locale environment variables.  https://gist.github.com/sl5net/dca65ebc6a8a0cfedf69435fc93df85d

Comment: After reinstalling Kubuntu, `rofi -show` works. I don't know the cause. Right now I haven't reinstalled all of the tools. I hope to be able to say more about this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not quite the same way, but you could use **wmctrl** to switch between windows from the console:

```
wmctrl -a [window_title]
```

This will activate the window where *[window_name]* is the full or partial title.

Get all window titles:

```
wmctrl -l
```

If you want to switch windows using wildcards, you may need to use a combination of wmctrl and other command-line tools such as grep or awk. Here's an example that uses wmctrl, grep, and awk to achieve this:

```
wmctrl -l | grep -i "window_title" | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 | xargs wmctrl -i -a
```

This command will search for the first window whose title contains "window_title" (case-insensitive) and activate it using wmctrl.

Please note that this example assumes you have wmctrl, grep, awk, and xargs installed on your system.